# Secure built-in user credentials for Kibana/ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

**Setup**

ElasticSearch v6.8

**Context**

I'm trying to build a couple of AMI's for ElasticSearch and Kibana using Packer.

I've been reading the official docs and have run into something confusing (for me at least)

I'm setting up the built-in users in ElasticSearch according to [this doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/7.2/built-in-users.html).  I'm using the `auto` option as opposed to `interactive`

```
bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto
```

Once this is done I need to modify the `kibana.yml` file to use the built-in user whilst communicating with ElasticSearch.  [This doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/using-kibana-with-security.html) describes what to do.  Essentially you add these two lines:

```
elasticsearch.username: "kibana"
elasticsearch.password: "kibanapassword"
```

**Questions**

1. How can I automatically read the password output for the built in Kibana user (`bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto`) so that I can add it to the `kibana.yml` file?
2. Is storing the password in plain text in the 'kibana.yml' file secure?  I fear it is not... but is there an alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For `elasticsearch-setup-passwords` rather than using `auto`, look into [`--batch`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-passwords.html#_parameters_15), so you can define the password and then use that for Kibana.
2. You probably want to use a [keystore for Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/secure-settings.html).